# Is application has GUI or running in background

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to get the exactly same list as in "Process" tab under "Apps" header in "Task Manager".

I am checking process with `MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.MainWindowTitle)` but it is still fetching some background running process

I tried with getting all the process using C# code, then filtering with  `MainWindowHandle` and `MainWindowTitle` properties to get the window name which are there in Process tab under Apps header in Task Manager, but wen I verified the result with actual Task Manager result it is not correct. In My case Calculator is running in background (not showing in UI), but Task Manager is showing correct result (showing under Background process header), where as in my console application it is getting in my result (expecting not to get)

```
var process = Process.GetProcesses()
                .Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero 
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.MainWindowTitle))
                .ToList();

foreach (var item in process)
{
     Console.WriteLine(++count + ". " + item.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

I expect "Calculator" (`item.MainWindowTitle`) not come in my result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwIyk.png)

Look at the image for more details (highlighted in red line)

Answer (score 2):

There is no official documentation for this, the closest you are going to get is [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=97606):

> How does it decide which process goes into which category?
>
> **These are terms that Task Manager simply made up**. The system itself doesn’t really care what kind of processes they are.
>
> - If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an “App”.
> - If the process is marked as critical, then Task Manager calls it a “Windows Process”.
> - Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a “Background Process”.

This summary might not be 100% correct for UWP apps. Maybe it checks to see if the process is suspended?

You should make sure `MainWindowHandle` is visible.

Your usage of `MainWindowHandle` is also problematic because Win32 does not have such a concept. There can be 0, 1 or multiple main windows in a process.